# calling multiple functions in @keydown vue3 error

Tags: javascript, vuejs3, keydown

I have two functions which I'm trying to call with an inside input tag using `@keydown="test(); numOnly();"`
and get the error `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'key')`

```
numOnly(event) {
  const numPattern = /[\d]/;
  const eventVal = event.key;
  if (!numPattern.test(eventVal)) {
    event.preventDefault();
  } else {
    return true;
  }
},
test() {
  console.log('Test function() called');
}
```

When I remove the `test()` function it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error should be telling you it's occurring on this line:

```js
var eventVal = event.key;
```

`Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'key')` means the object that 'key' is a property of (event) is undefined.  If you `console.log(event)` right before that line, I'm sure you'd get `undefined` proving the error message correct.  `event` is a parameter of your method, so the only reason it would be undefined is if nothing is being passed in.

Checking the [Vue docs](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/event-handling.html#accessing-event-argument-in-inline-handlers), you pass the original DOM event to a method using the special `$event` variable. Therefore, this should fix your error:

```html
<input @keydown="test(); numOnly($event);" />
```